# How to install twistedweb python library on a web server

Tags: python, sockets, webserver, twisted.web

I have a small application written in python using TwistedWeb. It is a chat server.
Everything is configured right now as for localhost.
All I want is to run this python script on a server(shared server provided by Fatcow.com).
I mean that the script will be working all the time and some clients will connect/disconnect to it. Fatcow gives me python 2.5 without any custom libraries. Is there a way and a tutorial how to make it work with TwistedWeb?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Fatcow.com support. They do not support SSH connections and do not support Python 2.7 with Twisted library, especially python socket application as server. So it is dead end.
**Question resolved.**

Answer (score 0):

the easy_install/pip modes of installation are very likely to fail because of broken dependencies. You will have to download the tar and build it yourself. See the attached link for more info on installing the same on CENTOS.

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#CanIinstallTwistedusingeasy_installorpip

Comment: How can I make install command without ssh? Fatcow does not allow for ssh connections.

Comment: maybe I have a bad hosting?

Comment: seems like you could be out of luck, you don't get a shell access and so you will have to live with the hosting providers installable software list via you cpanel interface - http://www.webhostingbillboards.com/hosting-features/fat-cow-ssh/

Comment: Thanks, I will try to get help from fatcow support. Maybe they can install python 2.7 with Twisted.